# JavaScript code sent Date to PHP page Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

it is not working for me.. is this correct. i doubt in this line `data: "ch=" + dropdown&"ch2=" + dropdown2&"ch3=" + dropdown3,` can any please check this ones for me

```
<script>
function dynamic_Select(dropdown) {
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: 'att-filt.php',
data: "ch=" + dropdown&"ch2=" + dropdown2&"ch3=" + dropdown3,
dataType: "html",
success: function(html){       $("#txtResult").html(html); $("#firstresult").css("display", "none");    }
}); 
}
</script>



<form>
<input type="text" id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
<input type="text" id="dropdown2" name="dropdown1">
<input type="text" id="dropdown3" name="dropdown2">
<input type="button" value="submit"  onclick="dynamic_Select(this.value)">
</form>
```

Comment: No the & needs to be inside the quotes

Comment: @mplungjan thanks.. i tried moving it to inside quots. but not working. console : `[23:08:35.667] ReferenceError: dynamic_Select is not defined @ ......./test.php:1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're concatenting it wrong. The `&` must be within quotes. and you're also missing the `concat` operator (`+`) at places

Yours :   `data: "ch=" + dropdown&"ch2=" + dropdown2&"ch3=" + dropdown3`

Correct : `data: "ch=" + dropdown + "&ch2=" + dropdown2 + "&ch3=" + dropdown3`

And `dropdown`, `dropdown2`, `dropdown3` values won't work the way they are. It must be selected from the element, like this :

```
data: "ch=" + $("#dropdown").val()+"&ch2=" + $("#dropdown2").val()+"&ch3=" +  $("#dropdown3").val()
```

And remove the `onclick` to use jQuery's `click` :

```
$("input[type=button]").on("click", function dynamic_Select() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'att-filt.php',
        data: "ch=" + dropdown + "&ch2=" + dropdown2 + "&ch3=" + dropdown3,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (html) {
            $("#txtResult").html(html);
            $("#firstresult").css("display", "none");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The ampersand `&` needs to be inside the quotes and you need the actual values too - it is not enough to just mention the dropdown names.

Try this

```
 data: "ch="  + $("#dropdown").val() +
      "&ch2=" + $("#dropdown2").val()+
      "&ch3=" + $("#dropdown3").val(),
```

Please note that your IDs also do not match your NAMEs so you may be confused as to what you are getting on the server

To put it in context of your Ajax call, you want

```
$("input[type=button]").on("click", function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'att-filt.php',
    data: "ch="  + $("#dropdown").val() +
         "&ch2=" + $("#dropdown2").val()+
         "&ch3=" + $("#dropdown3").val(),
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (html) {
        $("#txtResult").html(html);
        $("#firstresult").css("display", "none");
    }
  });
});
```

Alternatively use [seriealize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

```
$("input[type=button]").on("click", function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'att-filt.php',
    data:$("form").serialize(),
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (html) {
        $("#txtResult").html(html);
        $("#firstresult").css("display", "none");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks worked :) will accept this as answer in 7 min. stackoverflow asking me to wait :/